# How to perform operation for all values in certain range?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I've two fields which are as following

[image]

I want to perform some operations for all values in `RANGE(LOW_BASE, HIGH_BASE)` [including both values].
How can I perform such operations?

Comment: You mean array (`CSE`) formulas?

Comment: We need some more information here. What operations are you trying to perform? You've tagged "excel-formula", but include VBA in your description. What are you trying to do, exactly? This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I understand that u need to do operations on 33, 34, 35,... until 62. Just curious.. what is the operation? & will the result be a list or a single value?